# Cross-domain authentification with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have a web application built on Spring framework and running on Tomcat (lets call it exampleA.com). It has an API method for authentification - /securityLogin
And i have another site on a different domain (exampleB.com) that have an ability to send authentification request to examleA.com via API. And if the authentification is succesfull, user must be redirected to exampleA.com and be already authentificated. It all works fine by this point, session is created on the server, but user is not authentificated on examleA.com after redirect. I understand that this is because of my applications based on different domains, but i have no idea how can i fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i have found the solution. I've just added

```
xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
}
```

to my jQuery AJAX call, in order to allow JavaScript to pass my JSESSIONID cookie to the server